# Add linebreaks within conditionals using Roslyn Formatter

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I would like to format conditional statements such as

```
var x = (condition) ? iftrue : iffalse
```

like this:

```
var x =
    (condition)
    ? iftrue 
    : iffalse
```

This is especially useful when having lots of nested conditionals, like

```
var x =
    (condition)
    ? (condition)
        ? iftrue 
        : (condition)
            ? iftrue 
            : iffalse
    : (condition)
        ? iftrue 
        : iffalse
```

I'm generating these conditionals using `SyntaxFactory.ConditionalExpression`. After generating my code, I use the Roslyn Formatter (`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting`) to format my code:

```
var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var options = workspace.Options;
var node = Formatter.Format(@namespace, workspace, options);
var code = node.ToFullString();
```

I've tried using `WithCloseParenToken` and `TriviaList(LineFeed)` within the conditional expressions, but the formatter will remove those manually added linebreaks.

How can I tell the formatter to format conditionals the way I want them?

Comment: Opened as issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38255